How should I interpret からして when used in a sentence like 息子はもう30歳なのに、話し方からしてまだ子供っぽい?
According to most sources I can find, からして has two basic functions:

Used to state the basis from which a wider-ranging inference is made, often translated as "judging from", for example:
その映画のタイトルからして、面白くないと思う。 Judging from the title of the movie, I think it's not interesting.

Used to give an example having a characteristic which likely applies to all of the other things under consideration, often translated as "even", for example:
ひらがなからして読めない。 I cannot even read hiragana (so of course I can't read katakana or kanji either).


But then there are sentences such as 息子はもう30歳なのに、話し方からしてまだ子供っぽい. Should I interpret からして in sense 1 ('My son is already 30 years old, but based on the way he talks, he is still childish'), or in sense 2 ('My son is already 30 years old, but even the way he talks is still childish')?
If I put this sentence into Google translate, a get a different result:  My son is already 30, but he still talks like a child.
I feel that the Google translation carries a different connotation to either of the 2 uses mentioned above. If I interpret the Google translation literally, it is making a comment only on the way he talks, but other aspects of his behaviour may be mature.
Other examples that confuse me similarly are:
この子は笑い方からして母親にそっくりだ。 Is this saying that just the child's laughter is like its mother's, or that based on the laughter (or 'even' the laughter) is like its mother's (as well as probably lots of other traits)?
私は彼が嫌いだ。その態度からして許せない。 Is this saying that I cannot forgive his attitude (even though I could probably forgive other aspects of his behaviour), or that I cannot forgive even his attitude (so of course I cannot forgive any other aspects of his behaviour)? Or, 'based on his attitude, I cannot forgive him'?

See also Is there a difference between からすると and からして？.

This からして is used in the second sense. That is, his way of speaking alone indicates he's childish, among other aspects. からして in the first sense is usually paired with an expression of inference such as ようだ, そうだ and のように見える. More importantly, a parent usually wouldn't describe their son like "judging from how he speaks" — unless the parent saw their son for the first time in decades.
からして is used in the second sense also in the last two examples in your question. They mean "The way she laughs alone shows how much she's like her mother (although she is like her mother in many other ways)" and "(There are many reasons to hate him but) his attitude already makes him intolerable to me".

Thank you. That makes more sense to me now.
